Hazard ratio scale to Z-score scale - Freidlin Boundaries
In the paper A general inefficacy interim monitoring rule for randomized clinical trials, they propose boundaries for interim analyses using the hazard ratios. These boundaries are illustrated in an example aiming to test H0: HR = 1 vs H1: HR = 0.75. They show the boundaries in the hazard ratio scale and Z-value scale as below:

How can we transform from hazard ratio scale to Z-value scale?

Hazard ratios are more useful metrics for understanding the stopping boundary.  But you can convert between the two.  I believe an R package for group sequential testing does this.
